# 'One To Many' attribute value type should not be ________ Error

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I have 3 classes.
The relationship between User, Image, and Album is

1. a User can have many Images
2. a User can have many Albums

User class:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    Integer userId;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    String userFirstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    String userlastName;
    @Column(name="email")
    String userEmail;
    @Column(name="password")
    String userpswrd;
    @Column(name="profile_pik")
    String userProfilePik;

    @OneToMany
    List<Image> images; <-- this is fine

    @OneToMany
    List<Album> albums; <-- this is where I am getting error
```

The error I am getting is: 'One To Many' attribute value type should not be 'Album'

Here is my Album class

```
public class Album {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="album_id")
    int albumId;
    @Column(name="album_name")
    String albumName;
    @Column(name="album_date_added")
    Date albumDateAdded;
    @Column(name="album_date_modified")
    Date albumDateModified;
    @Column(name="album_notes")
    String albumNotes;
}
```

**My Question**: What is a possible fix to the error? even though the one-to-many mapping worked with Image class.

Comment: your album you must has attribute { private User user;}

Comment: @AbdalrhmanAlkraien Even after adding private User user in my album class, the error is still there